# Como executar um comando Python com JS?

Tags: javascript, python

Eu tenho um botão e ao clicar nele quero que o js execute um comando .py no lado servidor.
Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso através de um comando `AJAX` através do `JavaScript`, no entanto, sua chamada `AJAX` será uma solicitação na `HTTP` (WEB) para o script `Python`, portanto, seu comando precisa escutar na porta para tais solicitações e responder de volta.

> Abaixo segue um exemplo utilizando `jQuery` de como essa chamada pode
>   ser feita:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Python - jQuery Example</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/you-command.py",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "html",
                data: { var1: "foo", var2: "foo" },
                success: function(response){
                        $("#div").html(response);
                        console.log("OK"); 
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">EMPTY</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Caso seu script `Python` não aceite requisições `HTTP` será necessário adicionar uma camada que faça isso e execute seu comando, conforme desejado.

**`#EDIT`**

Basta você utilizar a biblioteca CGI do `Python`

```
import cgi, cgitb

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

output = data["var1"] // É assim que você captura os parâmetros passados.

print(output)
```

Comment: Então basicamente o Python tem que escutar uma requisição?

Comment: Como faço para o Python receber os parametros?

Comment: @renanprado96 é basicamente isso sim, eu editei a resposta mostrando uma forma simples de se capturar os parâmetros passados pelo `JS` no `Python`. Lembrando novamente que é necessário que o `script` em questão aceite `Requisições HTTP`, dê uma pesquisada na Internet que você descobre como, não vou explicar detalhadamente aqui porque foge do escopo da pergunta. Mas quaisquer dúvidas abra um novo tópico aqui no `SO` e lhe ajudaremos. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para isso vc precisa de uma camada entre o back-end e o front-end, algo como as templates do django, nesse caso voce teria um botão (que poderia ser "controlado" por js ou nao) que enviaria um objeto HTTP para uma função no back-end. Acho que com um exemplo fica mais fácil. Vamos supor apenas um botão submit para "acionar" algo no backend.

template.html

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" class="viewform">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <--! Implemente o form aqui -->

            <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def teste1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # Submit pressionado
       print ('Ok, botão pressionado)
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, 'template.html' )
```

### Observação:

É importante ter em mente que a idéia de um elemento no front-end executar, diretamente, um comando no back-end é uma **péssima** ideia, por isso a necessidade da camada intermediária, veja que nesse exemplo o botão não executa nada no back-end, ele apenas envia um request para o back e esse faz o que for necessário, ou seja, o front nem "sonha" se o que vai ser ser executado no back vai ser em python, c, ou bash. Isso garante que se houver a necessidade de alterar radicalmente a  linguagem/plataforma/ambiente em um dos lados, não ocorrerão efeitos co-laterais no outro.